# Django query a model since its creation to an X time

Tags: python, django

Having a such model:

```
class HelpRequest(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to query HelpRequest which are created within the last 5 mins, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
HelpRequest.objects.filter(creation_time__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)))
```

Comment: Now, Ain't Django and its ORM lovely??